# Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used

Tags: asp.net, eval

I try to recover a method from my aspx.cs page to my aspx page which allows me to return a string , so I did:

(...)

```
                <%= PrettyReqDAL(**Eval("Column").ToString()**, "OBP"))%>



            </DetailRow>
        </Templates>
        (..)
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

When I run, I receive this error:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the databinding syntax: `<%#  %>` instead of `<%=  %>`

Comment: I'm working with WCF, so when i do :                                                     <% using (TSO_SiteWeb.ServiceReference1.Service1Client wcf = new TSO_SiteWeb.ServiceReference1.Service1Client())
                       {%>
                    <%# PrettyReqDAL(wcf.ReqWcf(Eval("Column").ToString(), "OBP"))%>
                    <%}%> it doesn't work because it doesn't know the wcf.Prettyy..

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to mix databinding with service calls the way you imagine.

Comment: ok thanks, I resolved this problem, I used Eval in the codeBehind